# table notes out of margin

Tags: tables, footnotes

Hi I am using TeXnicCenter, I have problems by writing notes at the foot of a Table:
by using `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,psfig,a4,final]{article}  
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
 \begin {table}[htbp]  
 \centering  
 \begin{threeparttable}  
 \caption{Friendship Network Groups: Tie Strength\tmark[a] Comparison}  
 {\scriptsize{  
 \begin{center}  
 \begin{tabular}{p{.07\textwidth} p{.06\textwidth} p{.06\textwidth} p{.06\textwidth} p{.06\textwidth} p{.06\textwidth} p{.06\textwidth}}\\  
    \toprule  
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Network}} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{$\mathlarger{\sum}{w_e}$} &  \textbf{$Sd$} & \textbf{$n$} & \textbf{$u$} & \textbf{Median}\\\  
 & $\hat{w}_{e_{ij}}$ &  &  &  &  \\  
\midrule  
\textbf{$g_f$} & 4.24 & 16590 & 1.90 & 580 & 3910 & 4 \\[1.0em]  
\textbf{$g_{fS}$} & 4.34 & 4954 & 1.77 & 156 & 1151 & 4 \\[1.0em]  
    \textbf{$g_{fM}$} & 4.24 & 8525 & 1.95 & 418 & 1986 & 5 \\[1.0em]  
    \bottomrule   
\begin{tablenotes}  
\item[a]{Here is estimated tie strength as the value $w_e$ given by $i$ of the edge $ij$ through a likert scale.}  
\end{tablenotes}  
\end{tabular}   
\end{center}  
}}  
\end{threeparttable}  
\end{table}
```

The problem is that the note stays just in one colum and if it is a longer one, it does go up-down vertically (just in one column!) and not horizontally.
This may have an easy solution, but I have not found it jet! Does someone have a solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using `\tmark[a]` and you should use `\tnote{a}`, instead. You need to end the `tabular` environment *before* starting the `tablenotes` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,final]{article}  
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]  
\centering  
\begin{threeparttable}  
  \caption{Friendship Network Groups: Tie Strength\tnote{a} Comparison}  
  {\scriptsize 
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} 
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.1\textwidth}*{6}{p{.09\textwidth}}@{}}
  \toprule  
  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Network}} & \textbf{Mean} & $\displaystyle\sum{w_e}$ 
    & $\boldsymbol{Sd}$ & $\boldsymbol n$ & $\boldsymbol u$ & \textbf{Median}\\\  
  & $\hat{w}_{e_{ij}}$ & & & & \\  
  \midrule  
  $\boldsymbol{g_f}$ & 4.24 & 16590 & 1.90 & 580 & 3910 & 4 \\[1.0em]  
  $\boldsymbol{g_{fS}}$ & 4.34 & 4954 & 1.77 & 156 & 1151 & 4 \\[1.0em]  
  $\boldsymbol{g_{fM}}$ & 4.24 & 8525 & 1.95 & 418 & 1986 & 5 \\[1.0em]  
  \bottomrule   
\end{tabular}   
\begin{tablenotes}  
\item[a] Here is estimated tie strength as the value $w_e$ given by $i$ of the edge $ij$ through a likert scale.
\end{tablenotes}  
}  
\end{threeparttable}  
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not directly related, but `\scriptsize` doesn't have arguments; also notice that I used `\boldsymbol` (from the `bm` package) to get boldfaced math symbols. I suppressed `a4` and `psfig` from the list of class options, since they are not valid (perhaps you meant `a4paper`?). I also increases the width of the columns to prevent overfull boxes; to compensate, I locally reduced `\tabcolsep`.

Also, since your entries (at least the ones from the example) don't span more than one line, perhaps you can use `l` columns instead of `p{...}` ones:

```
\documentclass[12pt,final]{article}  
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]  
\centering  
\begin{threeparttable}  
  \caption{Friendship Network Groups: Tie Strength\tnote{a} Comparison}  
  {\scriptsize 
  \begin{tabular}{@{}*{7}{l}@{}}
  \toprule  
  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Network}} & \textbf{Mean} & $\displaystyle\sum{w_e}$ 
    & $\boldsymbol{Sd}$ & $\boldsymbol n$ & $\boldsymbol u$ & \textbf{Median}\\\  
  & $\hat{w}_{e_{ij}}$ & & & & \\  
  \midrule  
  $\boldsymbol{g_f}$ & 4.24 & 16590 & 1.90 & 580 & 3910 & 4 \\[1.0em]  
  $\boldsymbol{g_{fS}}$ & 4.34 & 4954 & 1.77 & 156 & 1151 & 4 \\[1.0em]  
  $\boldsymbol{g_{fM}}$ & 4.24 & 8525 & 1.95 & 418 & 1986 & 5 \\[1.0em]  
  \bottomrule   
\end{tabular}   
\begin{tablenotes}  
\item[a] Here is estimated tie strength as the value $w_e$ given by $i$ of the edge $ij$ through a likert scale.
\end{tablenotes}  
}  
\end{threeparttable}  
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried before also with `\tnote{}`, however, I did not change the `\end{Tabular}`. Now it works perfectly.  The `\boldsymbol` is alson a good comment, and the `a4` was indeed realated to the `a4paper`!